Smart contract monitoring
When using WebSocket to monitor smart contracts, disconnections can lead to incomplete data. On the other hand, using HTTP polling to listen for data results in significant delays.
How can low latency and data integrity be achieved when listening to smart contract event data?

This question is similar to: My program event listeners sometimes miss Anchor events?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
